# Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln({1+ n^{-4/3}})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to check if this series converges or diverges? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\left({1+ \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{n}}}\right)$$
I've tried using comparison test so. 
$$c_n=\ln\left(\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}\right) <\ln\left({1+ \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{n}}}\right)<\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=b_n$$
By integral test $c_n$ and $a_n$ is divergent, so initial series should be divergent too. But using wolfram mathematica it shows that series is convergent. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using comparison test wrong

Comment: In this case it's better to use the Maclaurin series for $\log(1+x)$. Or just compare to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$.

Comment: Can you answer it in more details, please?

Comment: For better understanding, please read again the definition and conditions for the comparison test and see how to do it right. I'm not going to provide the full solution, but I'm sure someone else will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for any $x\ge0 \implies \log(1+x)\le x$, therefore

$$0\le \ln\left({1+ \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{n}}}\right)\le  \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{n}}$$

and since $\sum \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{n}}$ converges by $p$ test also the given series converges by comparison test.

Comment: You might want to add the (obvious) lower bound $0\le\log(1+x)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes that was implicitely assumed since $1+ \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{n}}\ge 1$, thanks for your kind suggestion. Bye

Comment: A lower bound that can be used to prove divergence (when the sum actually divergences, not this case) is $\ln(1+x) > x/2$ for  small enough $x$. Probably $0 < x < 1/2 $ works.

Comment: @martycohen Or just use $ \ln(1+x) \sim x$ and limit comparison test to cover both cases.

Comment: You don't need limits. By the alternating series result, $x-x^2/2 < \ln(1+x) < x$ for $ 0<x<1$.

Comment: @martycohen That's a really nice way! But when we don't know or don't remember such inequalities limit comparison test is a good friend of us! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Since$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}x=\log'1=1,$$you have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1{n\sqrt[3]n}\right)}{\frac1{n\sqrt[3]n}}=1.$$So, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\sqrt[3]n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-\frac43}$ converges, your series converges too.